# Django @login_required dropping https

Tags: django, ssl, https, nginx

I'm trying to test my Django app locally using SSL. I have a view with the `@login_required` decorator. So when I hit `/locker`, I get redirected to `/locker/login?next=/locker`. This works fine with http.

However, whenever I use https, the redirect somehow drops the secure connection, so I get something like `https://cumulus.dev/locker -> http://cumulus.dev/locker/login?next=/locker`

If I go directly to `https://cumulus.dev/locker/login?next=locker` the page opens fine over a secure connection. But once I enter the username and password, I go back to `http://cumulus.dev/locker`.

I'm using Nginx to handle the SSL, which then talks to `runserver`. My nginx config is

```
upstream app_server_djangoapp {
server localhost:8000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
listen 80;
server_name cumulus.dev;

access_log  /var/log/nginx/cumulus-dev-access.log;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/cumulus-dev-error.log info;

keepalive_timeout 5;

# path for static files
root /home/gaurav/www/Cumulus/cumulus_lightbox/static;

location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        proxy_pass http://app_server_djangoapp;
        break;
    }
}
}

server {
listen 443;
server_name cumulus.dev;

ssl on;
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/cacert-cumulus.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/privkey.pem;

access_log  /var/log/nginx/cumulus-dev-access.log;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/cumulus-dev-error.log info;

keepalive_timeout 5;

# path for static files
root /home/gaurav/www/Cumulus/cumulus_lightbox/static;

location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        proxy_pass http://app_server_djangoapp;
        break;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I was going to say, "Oh, just change the `LOGIN_URL` in your `settings.py` file" ... but I tried that and it doesn't work. Good Question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django is running on plain HTTP only behind the proxy, so it will always use that to construct absolute URLs (such as redirects), unless you configure it how to see that the proxied request was originally made over HTTPS.

As of Django 1.4, you can do this using the [`SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#secure-proxy-ssl-header) setting. When Django sees the configured header, it will treat the request as HTTPS instead of HTTP: `request.is_secure()` will return true, `https://` URLs will be generated, and so on.

However, note the security warnings in the documentation: you *must* ensure that the proxy replaces or strips the trusted header from all incoming client requests, both HTTP and HTTPS. Your nginx configuration above does not do that with `X-Forwarded-Ssl`, making it spoofable.

A conventional solution to this is to set `X-Forwarded-Protocol` to `http` or `https`, as appropriate, in each of your proxy configurations. Then, you can configure Django to look for it using:

```
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTOCOL', 'https')
```

Comment: Thank you! :) I made it work using Gunicorn, but I remember setting the headers but couldn't use the header setting because I'm still on 1.3!

Comment: @GauravDadhania do you remember how you figured this out? I'm looking to answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29737089/how-do-i-use-a-login-redirect-with-https-in-django